# API Publisher sequence error

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I've been trying to enable the XACML by using the Identity Server as the PDP an API Manager the PEP. I'm running APIM 2.0.0 and IDS 5.2.0. I followed the instructions on this [page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML). I can't seem to get it working. I get these errors whenever I try adding the EntitlementMediator.xml to the in flow of the API.

```
[2017-02-01 13:48:35,451] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.sequences.services.SequenceAdmin} -  Invalid sequence definition {org.wso2.carbon.sequences.services.SequenceAdmin}
```

---

### Caused By

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error adding sequence : Invalid sequence definition
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation$RobustOutOnlyOperationClient.handleResponse(RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation.java:91)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.stub.types.SequenceAdminServiceStub.addSequence(SequenceAdminServiceStub.java:3288)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.utils.SequenceAdminServiceClient.addSequence(SequenceAdminServiceClient.java:49)
    ... 63 more

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.sequences.common.SequenceEditorException: Invalid sequence definition
    at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.services.SequenceAdmin.handleException(SequenceAdmin.java:651)
    at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.services.SequenceAdmin.addSequence(SequenceAdmin.java:417)
    ... 81 more
```

---

### Error in Carbon log

```
 [2017-02-01 13:48:35,452] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.sequences.services.SequenceAdmin} -  Error adding sequence : Invalid sequence definition {org.wso2.carbon.sequences.services.SequenceAdmin} org.wso2.carbon.sequences.common.SequenceEditorException: Invalid sequence definition 
    at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.services.SequenceAdmin.handleException(SequenceAdmin.java:651) 
    at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.services.SequenceAdmin.addSequence(SequenceAdmin.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.stub.types.SequenceAdminServiceStub.addSequence(SequenceAdminServiceStub.java:3288)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.utils.SequenceAdminServiceClient.addSequence(SequenceAdminServiceClient.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.service.APIGatewayAdmin.addSequence(APIGatewayAdmin.java:256)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also had troubles adding the API Manager carbon XACML features. I got this error message.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: XACML Feature 5.0.7 
(org.wso2.carbon.identity.xacml.feature.group 5.0.7) Software currently installed: Identity XACML Server Feature 5.2.0 
(org.wso2.carbon.identity.xacml.server.feature.group 5.2.0)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: Identity XACML Server Feature 5.0.7
(org.wso2.carbon.identity.xacml.server.feature.jar 5.0.7) Identity XACML Server Feature 5.2.0 
(org.wso2.carbon.identity.xacml.server.feature.jar 5.2.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: XACML Feature 5.0.7 
(org.wso2.carbon.identity.xacml.feature.group 5.0.7) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.xacml.server.feature.group [5.0.7] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Identity XACML Server Feature 5.0.7 
(org.wso2.carbon.identity.xacml.server.feature.group 5.0.7) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.xacml.server.feature.jar [5.0.7] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Identity XACML Server Feature 5.2.0 
(org.wso2.carbon.identity.xacml.server.feature.group 5.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.xacml.server.feature.jar [5.2.0]
```

Also I'm not 100% sure what I should be adding to the sequence code seen below. I know to change the remoteServiceUrl to match are service, but we have a cluster environment where to login in we go through shibboleth. So I'm not sure if I need remoteServiceUserName and remoteServicePassword.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  name="EntitlementMediator">     
<entitlementService xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" remoteServiceUrl="https://localhost:9444/services" remoteServiceUserName="admin" remoteServicePassword="admin" callbackClass="org.wso2.sample.handlers.entitlement.APIEntitlementCallbackHandler"/>
```

I'm a beginner to sequences and mediators and I'm finding the process a little hard to understand. So if I'm way off please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have a caused by block in the exception trace?

Comment: I added the caused by from the carbon log to the original post. Thank you for the comment :)